# How do I create a new column with values that depend on the values in other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Here is a very simple toy data set to illustrate a problem that I am currently encountering with another data set.

Suppose we have tested 4 participants in a math test, where each of them answered 4 questions. 2 of these questions were easy, and 2 of them were difficult. But the questions were presented in random order, so some people started with an easy question and some people started with a difficult question. And we have a binary response variable in this experiment, where we classified the answers as either "correct" or "incorrect."

Here is the fake data:

```
my_matrix <- matrix(c(rep(1:4, each=4), rep(1:4, 4), rep(c("difficult", "easy"), times = 4), rep(c("easy", "difficult"), times = 4), rep(c("correct", "incorrect"), times = 8)), nrow=16, ncol=4, byrow = FALSE)

my_matrix

my_data_frame <- as.data.frame(my_matrix)

colnames(my_data_frame) <- c("Participant", "ItemNumber", "QuestionDifficulty", "Answer")

my_data_frame$Participant <- as.numeric(my_data_frame$Participant)

my_data_frame
```

Now, I want to create a new column such that its value is "DifficultFirst" for people who started with a difficult question and "EasyFirst" for people who started with an easy question. I tried the following code for this.

```
for (i in 1:16) {
  ifelse(my_data_frame$Participant == i & my_data_frame$ItemNumber == 1 & my_data_frame$QuestionDifficulty =="difficult",
         my_data_frame$FirstQuestion[((i*4)-3):(i*4)] <- "DifficultFirst",
         my_data_frame$FirstQuestion[((i*4)-3):(i*4)] <- "EasyFirst")}
```

But it didn't work. Specifically, I got an error message about the replacement and the data not matching in terms of their row numbers, and I don't know why this is the case.

It is late in the day and my brain may be too tired, so apologies if this is a silly question. But any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can use various grouping operations. This arranges the data by `Participant` and `ItemNumber`, group it by `Participant` and gets the first value of `QuestionDifficulty`.

```
library(dplyr)

my_data_frame %>%
  arrange(Participant, ItemNumber) %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(FirstQuestion = paste0(first(QuestionDifficulty), "first"))

#   Participant ItemNumber QuestionDifficulty Answer    FirstQuestion 
#         <dbl> <fct>      <fct>              <fct>     <chr>         
# 1           1 1          difficult          correct   difficultfirst
# 2           1 2          easy               incorrect difficultfirst
# 3           1 3          difficult          correct   difficultfirst
# 4           1 4          easy               incorrect difficultfirst
# 5           2 1          difficult          correct   difficultfirst
# 6           2 2          easy               incorrect difficultfirst
# 7           2 3          difficult          correct   difficultfirst
# 8           2 4          easy               incorrect difficultfirst
# 9           3 1          easy               correct   easyfirst     
#10           3 2          difficult          incorrect easyfirst     
#11           3 3          easy               correct   easyfirst     
#12           3 4          difficult          incorrect easyfirst     
#13           4 1          easy               correct   easyfirst     
#14           4 2          difficult          incorrect easyfirst     
#15           4 3          easy               correct   easyfirst     
#16           4 4          difficult          incorrect easyfirst
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Just out of curiosity, do you think there would be a way of solving this with a loop as well?

Comment: yes, there would be but it is not ideal in this situation as it would be highly inefficient doing it with `for` loop.